# Can't register Norton Anti-virus?

Tags: norton-antivirus

I was trying to install Norton Anti-virus on Windows 7 from the Internet connection at the library and even if I turned the firewall off (and later turned it back on), it could not access the `create an account` function of the software.  I kept getting an `unable to access server` error.  Is it possible that the library is blocking it?  Or is there some other issue?

Comment: Downvote?  Sorry I'm just not familiar with the non-SEP version of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently needed to help a friend install Norton. We needed to [create the account via the Norton website](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v63577240_identity_safe_standalone_1_en_us) as it didn’t work via the software interface.

Once you create an account that way, just register the key online to add it to your account.

Then from the website there’ll be a download link to install a registered version of the software that uses your key. Installing this will probably cause an uninstall of the version you currently have installed, then it will install the new version.